# How to prevent Hibernate load the whole collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

For example, I have the following entity:

```
class User{
    ...
    private Set questions;
    ...
}
```

When I operate the domain model:

```
  user.questions.add(...);
```

`Hibernate` will load ALL the questions of this collection, even if I set the collection to `LAZY`. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to annotate the collection with

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Don't do this, load all the collection on request.

**Details**

I think you should reconsider your desire to avoid loading the collection when its elements are updated via `add()` method call. Here are my arguments:

- When you add element, the result (i.e. whether element added or not) might depend on type of the collection. For `Set` - it definetely depends on collection contents.
- In terms of business logic, your `Set` represents some questions related to user. Let's imagine you achieved the result you want - first five questions are in the collection, the rest ten are not. What is the business meaning of the collection then? Sounds really questionable.

If you consider my arguments bad, feel free to use the techniques described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

So actual problem description: when I apply cascading there is a performance issue because there can be many questions.

My answer would then be: then don't use cascading to save questions, persist the question using a regular EntityManager.persist() call.

Pretty obvious, right?

Answer (score -2):

If the resultSet size is very huge you can do it in batches by setting max limits

```
query.setMaxResults(int maxResults)
```

Comment: This is not a way to limit the number of results in `xxx-to-xxx`-mapped collection. This is the way to limit the number of entities retreived by query.